# instance_eval doesn't work with att_accessor?

Tags: ruby, block, instance-eval

Can anybody say me, why that isn't working:

```
class A
  attr_accessor :b
end

a = A.new
a.instance_eval do
  b = 2
end

a.b
=> nil
```

What is wrong i'm doing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The culprit lies in this part of the code:

```
a.instance_eval do
  b = 2
end
```

Although `b = 2` is evaluated in the context of your instance, it doesn't call the setter. Instead it just creates a new local variable called `b` in the current scope. To call the setter, you have to further clarify your code to resolve the ambiguity:

```
a.instance_eval do
  self.b = 2
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
a.instance_eval do
  self.b = 2
end
```